# Can't save and display data using Service/IntentService properly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice

I am updaiting database on each app launch, i was using `IntentService` before, but my activity was starting before data is updated, so data list was empty, i have rewriten it using `Service`(i have created my own `Service` acting like `IntentService` so i could controll thread created by the `Service`). As you see first of all i am saving data, and only after that i am starting my activity. But my activity is starting before data is saved anyway, any suggestions why, or how can i fix this?

**Also**

If you have some expirience working with ORM/Database async it would be great, i am just trying to learn how to work with database properly. Any suggestions are apreciated.

```
public class DatabaseWorkService extends Service {
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private ConnectivityManager conMan;
    private NetworkInfo netInfo;
    private String currentTask;
    private Intent tempIntent;
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;
    private Context context =this;
    public DatabaseWorkService delegate = null;


    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.getData()!=null) {
                switch (msg.getData().getString(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE)) {
                    case Utils.LOAD_All_DATA: {
                        saveActivities();
                        savePersons();
                        savePictureData();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Log.e("order", "forth");
                        break;
                    }
                    case Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA: {
                        readActionData();
                        break;
                    }
                    case Utils.READ_PERSONS_DATA: {
                        readPersonsData();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments");
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("service","service started");

        Log.e("data",intent.getStringExtra(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE));

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE,intent.getStringExtra(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE));

        // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
        // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: saveActivities();savePersons();savePictureData(); is these method return any value. if not can you do that

Comment: They, don't return any values, i'l try in in an hour, but how it could change the behavoiur?

Comment: @jiteshmohite I have added return values, nothing chaged.

Answer (score 0):

if these quires returning any values after insertion in database, then only you have to launch activity

```
                saveActivities();
                savePersons();
                savePictureData();
```

try below code launch your activity inside Main thread handler

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                              Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: No changes, what is the correct way to work with database? I have tried to query database using AsyncLoader, but even if i am starting activity inside onFinishLoad, my activity is empty anyway.

Comment: can you post your activity and menifest so that i can try at my end

Comment: Here goes the whole project https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-pbp_K-xNkEZjVibWphZ2ZNRnM

Comment: link contains .rar file can you attach compress file or you can email your code jiteshmohite619@gmail.com

Comment: Its a rar archive of my project, just open it, il send it to your email in some time.